# Proof: $m,n$ are integers: either $4$ divides $mn$ or else $4$ does not divide $n$.

Tags: logic

I'm having some trouble in proving the following statement:

> If $m$ and $n$ are integers, then either $4$ divides $mn$ or else $4$ does not divide $n$.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: I would think about three cases. $m$ and$n$ are both even, both odd, have different parity.

Comment: Try rewriting your statement "P or Q" as "not Q implies P"

Comment: Is this true? "Either A or B" means exactly one of A and B, but not both. So, $m = n = 2$ is a counterexample. Or does "Either A or else B" mean something else than "either A or B"?

Comment: @Magdiragdag I'm not sure whether "either $A$ or else $B$" connotes "not both $A$ and $B$" in English, but in mathematical logic we would ignore the "either" and the "else" and consider the "or" as "inclusive or".

Comment: I sure wouldn't interpret "either...or" as inclusive or. Then again, if I'd use "either...or", I'd always make sure the two options are extremely obviously mutually exclusive, or explicitly add "but not both".

Comment: @Magdiragdag I would suggest that in mathematical writing you explicitly add "but not both" if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes, that's what I do.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** This is equivalent to proving that if $4$ divides $n$ then $4$ divides $mn$.

Comment: Thanks! I understand it better now!

Comment: @wonggr It might help to think in terms of arbitrary statements $P$ and $Q$.  The implication $P \implies Q$ is equivalent (in classical logic) to the disjunction $\neg P \vee Q$.  The only way the implication is false is if $P$ is true, but $Q$ is still false.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a truth table:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|l}
\hline 4\text{ divides } n & 4\text{ divides }mn & 4\text{ does not divide }n &  \\
\hline
T & T & \text{?} \\
f & f & \text{?} \\
f & T & \text{?} & \longleftarrow\text{ This hapens if}\ldots \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
. . . The situation in the third row happens if $2$ divides both $n$ and $m$, or if $4$ divides $m$.

Fill in the last column of the truth table, then ask whether it is true in in row that either $4$ divides $mn$ or $4$ does not divide $n$.